# How to display first post thumbnail as a background image of a widget?

Tags: widgets, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I have a regular WordPress Widget that display few posts using `WP_Query` 
I'm trying to find a way to display the thumbnail of the first post as a background image for the entire widget div.
Here's the visual representation of what I need:

[image: visual representation]

The code that I use right now displays a thumbnail for every post:

```
<div class="widget-wrap-sidebar">
<div class="my-widget">

<?php
// THE QUERY
?>

<?php
global $wp_query;
$metakey = 'post_views_count';
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $categories, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'meta_key' => $metakey, 'posts_per_page' => $posts ) );
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $recent_posts;
?>

<?php while( $recent_posts->have_posts() ): $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>

<div class="big-image">
<?php if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<?php $thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'big-image' ); ?>
<?php  echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail_url ); ?>
<?php endif;?>
</div>


<div class="the-title">
<h3>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
</a>
</h3>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div><?php // end of my-widget ?>
</div><?php // end of widget-wrap-sidebar ?>
```

Basically, I need a way to call for the thumbnail URL on the first `widget-wrap-sidebar` div. Something like this:

```
<div class="widget-wrap-sidebar" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>')">
```

However, I've been unable to make the above code work.
* Please do not consider the CSS part that I can accomplish with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few notes:

- Just use `the_title()`; instead of `echo get_the_title();`
- Use [`the_title_attribute()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title_attribute/) for title attributes.
- No need to override the global `$wp_query` when you use a secondary query.
- Then use `wp_reset_postdata()` after your secondary query loop.
- Use `the_permalink()` that escapes the permalink, instead of the unescaped `echo get_permalink();`
- There's the [`has_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) to check if the post thumbnail is set.
- Note that `get_the_post_thumbnail()` returns the post thumbnail image tag, not the url.
- Check out [`the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url) to get the thumbnail url.
- To check for the first item in your secondary recent posts loop, you can use `if( 0 === $recent_posts->current_post ){` within that loop.

### Example:

Here's an example (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $recent_posts )
{
    $thumbnail_url = 'https://example.tld/default.png'; // fallback post thumbnail url
    $data          = [];

    // Loop    
    while( $recent_posts->have_posts() )
    {
        $recent_posts->the_post();

        // Post thumbnail from the first post
        if( 0 === $recent_posts->current_post )
            $thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'medium' );

        // Collect post titles
        $data[] = the_title(
            sprintf(
                '<div class="title"><h3><a href="%s">',
                esc_url( get_permalink() )
            ),                 // before
            '</a></h2></div>', // after
            false              // echo
        );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Output
    if( $data )
        printf(
            '<div class="widget-wrap-sidebar" style="background-image: url(%s)">
                 <div class="my-widget">%s</div>
             </div>',
            esc_url( $thumbnail_url ),
            join( '', $data )
        );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your valuable tips. Your sugestion works great but what I need, to have more CSS flexibility, is to set a background image like that: `<div class="widget-wrap-sidebar" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>')">` Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: One approach for your inline styling could be: `<style>.widget-wrap-sidebar{ background-image: url( <?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail_url ); ?>);}</style>`after your successful loop, where you could use a fallback image if the first post (or any of the other posts) doesn't have a featured image? @AlexandruAndreiCostache

Comment: I'm a bit confusing about "after your successful loop" Can you post your comment as a sample code so I can accept the answer please? Thank you @birgire

Comment: I updated with an example @AlexandruAndreiCostache